# Protractor globals missing after npm install

Tags: typescript, protractor

I deleted all files inside `node_modules` in the project and run the following command

```
>npm install
```

Then I get below error in my script file.

[image]

Below is my dependencies in `package.json`

```
 "dependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "codelyzer": "^0.0.28",
    "jasmine-bamboo-reporter": "0.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.2.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.5.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "protractor": "^4.0.4",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "ts-node": "^1.2.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.5",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: run typings install again?

Comment: @toskv I ran `npm install typings `. No difference

Comment: no.. just "typings install".. so typings goes and fetches any .d.ts files in case they were deleted. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`protractor/globals` have been removed from `v4.0.9`, though it was a breaking change for typescript users, the protractor team decided to go with a patch semver.

So now you can just use `import {browser} from 'protractor'` directly which is much cleaner.

For more details checkout the protractor [changelog](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#409).